# CSS for only iPhone and only regular browsers?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, css

I have a website that looks horrible on the iPhone but fine in regular browsers. I want to be able to only load css for the iPhone and only load the other stylesheet for regular browsers. I would rather not use PHP but it is an available option, I'd like to use the standard way to call css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
```

Comment: define 'regular browser'

Comment: Safari, firefox, chrome, camino, opera....

Comment: I'm being a little pendantic, but keep in mind that all those 'regular' browsers also run on handheld devices. I think what you really are asking is how to deliver custom CSS to a particular device based on its screen size (ie, mobile) regardless of the browser it uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with CSS media queries. This will serve a mobile stylesheet to devices with a screen no wider than 768 pixels, and a desktop screenshot to the others.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 768px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

Comment: I like this solution. I also wonder how Safari would handle this on an iPhone 4 when switching between landscape mode (960px wide) and portrait mode (640px wide).

Comment: Turns out orientation can be specified as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329110/css-media-queries-for-iphone

Comment: What I'm looking for, I just changed the `max-device-width` to `(max-device-width: 480px)` so that it included landscape, portrait, and excluded the iPad and regular browsers.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is CSS **media queries**. The let you specify which css rules to use based on different browser resolutions / screen dpi. You can read more about them at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 2):

If php is an option one thing you can do is install user agent processing tool to find from which device the request has come and you can tailor your website accordingly.

WURLF works well for me.
There is open source MYSQL-PHP library for that:

[TERA-WURFL](http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

If you don't want that and looking for a single solution you can use something like this in your css:

```
// target small screens (mobile devices or small desktop windows)
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* CSS goes here */
}

/* high resolution screens */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
             (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
             (min-resolution: 300dpi) {
  header { background-image: url(header-highres.png); }
}

/* low resolution screens */
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
             (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
             (max-resolution: 299dpi) {
  header { background-image: url(header-lowres.png); }
}
```

You can read more about this at this good blog post:

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript

Comment: User agent parsing will always be problematic.

Comment: Not "everyone", and "lots of people are doing that" is a pretty dumb argument. Plenty of people do heroin, too. The simple fact of the matter is that user agent parsing requires you to stay on top of frequent updates - there are new phones being released every day - or risk shitty experiences for some phone owners.