# Sidebar is blocking content on iPhone

Tags: wordpress

If you visit http://www.windowswave.com on an iPhone, you'll see that my site's grey sidebar is blocking out the entire content section.

The sidebar isn't supposed to show on the iPhone, but it does now after doing some customization to my WordPress theme. I'm just not sure how to fix this.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
    .sidebar{
         display:none;
     }
}
```

for more info visit this [CSS media queries for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329110/css-media-queries-for-iphone)

Comment: Thanks, I placed this in my screen.css file and it worked beautifully! I changed the max-device-width to 640px since the iPhone 5 has a 1136x640 pixels display. I'm really a novice at CSS and you just made my day! Thanks again, so much!